# Responsive Site Nav Toggle not responding

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am creating a responsive web page for an education institution.I have used a free template available credit to the designer.

In mobile view when i scroll up in chrome (the address bar hides in below snapshot) then the blue color nav toggle(menubar) is not responsive.

[image: not respnsive]
After scroll down(now address bar is visible in below snapshot) Nav toggle works fine.

[image: Working fine]

My js code

```
$.fn.dropdownMenu = function(opt) {
return $(this).each(function() {
    var el = $(this),
        optsDefault = {
            menuClass: 'dropdown-menu-list',
            breakpoint: 1000,
            toggleClass: 'active',
            classButtonToggle: 'toggle-menu',
            subMenu: {
                class: 'sub-menu',
                parentClass: 'menu-item-has-children',
                toggleClass: 'active'
            }
        },
        options = $.extend({}, optsDefault, opt);
    el.on('dropdownMenu', function() {
        $('.' + options.classButtonToggle, el).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.' + options.menuClass, el).toggleClass(options.toggleClass);
        });
        $('.' + options.subMenu.parentClass, el).on('click', '> a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = $(this);
            self.next('.' + options.subMenu.class).slideToggle(400);
            self.parent().toggleClass(options.subMenu.toggleClass);
        });
        $(document).on('click', function() {
            $('.' + options.menuClass, el).removeClass(options.toggleClass);
            $('.' + options.subMenu.parentClass, el).removeClass(options.subMenu.toggleClass);
            $('.' + options.subMenu.class, el).hide();
        });
        $('.' + options.menuClass).on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
    if (window.innerWidth <= options.breakpoint) {
        el.trigger('dropdownMenu');
    }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if (window.innerWidth <= options.breakpoint) {
            el.trigger('dropdownMenu');
        } else {
            $('.' + options.classButtonToggle, el).off('click');
            $('.' + options.subMenu.parentClass, el).off('click', '> a');
            $('html, body').off('click');
            $('.' + options.menuClass).off('click');
        }
    });
});
```

}

My Html code

```
<div class="page-wrap">

        <!-- header -->
        <header class="header header--fixed">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header__inner">
                    <div class="header__logo">Wisdom Learning<a href="index.html"><!--<img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""/>--></a></div>
                    <div class="header__menu">

                        <!-- onepage-nav -->
                        <nav class="onepage-nav">

                            <!-- onepage-menu -->
                            <ul class="onepage-menu">
                                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#id-1">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#id-2">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#id-3">Products</a>


                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#id-4">Press</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#id-5">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul><!-- onepage-menu -->

                            <div class="navbar-toggle"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                        </nav><!-- End / onepage-nav -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header><!-- End / header -->

        <!-- Content-->
        <div class="md-content">

            <!-- hero -->
            <div class="hero" id="id-1" style="background-image: url('assets/img/bg/1.jpg');">
                <div class="hero__wrapper">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8 ">
                                <h1 class="hero__title">We make learning<br/>


                                    <!-- typing__module -->
                                    <div class="typing__module" data-options='{"typeSpeed":60}'>
                                        <div class="typed-strings"><span>Interactive</span><span>Easy</span><span>Fun</span>
                                        </div><span class="typed"></span>
                                    </div><!-- End / typing__module -->

                                </h1>

                            </div>
                        </div><span id="back-to-down">Know more</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- End / hero -->


            <!-- Section -->
            <section class="md-section bg-gray" id="id-2">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-5 ">

                            <!-- slide-image -->
                            <div class="slide-image">

                                <!-- swiper__module swiper-container -->
                                <div class="swiper__module swiper-container slide-image__front" data-options='{"slidesPerView":1,"spaceBetween":0}'>
                                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                        <div class="slide-item" style="background-image: url('assets/img/about/1.jpg');"></div>
                                        <div class="slide-item" style="background-image: url('assets/img/about/2.jpg');"></div>
                                        <div class="slide-item" style="background-image: url('assets/img/about/3.jpg');"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-pagination-custom"></div>
                                </div><!-- End / swiper__module swiper-container -->


                                <!-- swiper-thumbnails__module swiper-container -->
                                <div class="swiper-thumbnails__module swiper-container slide-image__black" data-options='{"slidesPerView":1,"spaceBetween":0,"delay":10000}'>
                                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                        <div class="slide-item" style="background-image: url('assets/img/about/1b.jpg');"></div>
                                        <div class="slide-item" style="background-image: url('assets/img/about/2b.jpg');"></div>
                                        <div class="slide-item" style="background-image: url('assets/img/about/3b.jpg');"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- End / swiper-thumbnails__module swiper-container -->

                            </div><!-- End / slide-image -->

                        </div>
```

and CSS code

```
.onepage-nav {
z-index: 999;}    

.onepage-nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 0;
}

.onepage-nav li {
position: relative;
z-index: 9;
}

.onepage-nav li a {
display: block;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1201px) {
.onepage-nav {
    text-align: center;
}

.onepage-nav li:hover > a {
    color: #19c2c9;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 2px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu li {
    background-color: #111;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu li:first-child {
    padding-top: 18px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu a {
    color: #eee;
    padding: 2px 25px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu a:after {
    right: 15px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #748182;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu {
    display: block !important;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-parent > a,
.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu .current-menu-item > a {
    color: #19c2c9;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .current-menu-parent > a,
.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .current-menu-item > a {
    color: #19c2c9;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu {
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu li:hover > a {
    color: #4aa8ff;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-toggle-menu {
    display: none;
}
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
.onepage-nav .onepage-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    will-change: transform;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a:after {
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu {
    background-color: #111;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
    color: #eee;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a:after {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu {
    left: 0;
    width: 280px;
    background-color: #111;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0);
            transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.onepage-nav .active.onepage-menu {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
            transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu {
    z-index: 99999;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    text-align: left;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a {
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #748182;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .active > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .current-menu-parent > a,
.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .current-menu-item > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu a {
    padding: 12px 15px;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children > a:hover {
    color: #4aa8ff;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-menu .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children.active > a {
    color: #4aa8ff;
}

.onepage-nav .onepage-toggle-menu {
    display: block;
}
}

.onepage-nav {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.onepage-nav li.current a {
color: #19c2c9;
}

.onepage-menu.active ~ .navbar-toggle span:nth-child(1) {
top: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.onepage-menu.active ~ .navbar-toggle span:nth-child(2) {
opacity: 0;
left: -40px;
}

.onepage-menu.active ~ .navbar-toggle span:nth-child(3) {
top: 10px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

I think its link between click event and position of my nav bar has some issue
Please help with the solution as to Nav toggle should work all time irrespective of its position.

Link to my webpage: [here](http://be5411f1.ngrok.io/wis/index.html)

Comment: Your link is a local url, that is not accessible to anyone but yourself. You can put your full code in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen) instead.

Comment: My bad.Edited it with a tunnel link......Please try now.

Comment: The website view seems to be responsive, perhaps you mean the bottom stripe of the menu toggle isn't the same width as the other 2?

Comment: I mean if you scroll web page up in chrome the toggle doesnt work.You  scroll down atleast once then it works.

Comment: The problem is that your toggle only works at a certain width, so when the width is too much it will already show the toggle menu, but doesn't work.

Comment: I inspected the element in Desktop chrome its showing same width of 30 px on both part.No issue there it seems .But when i refresh the page it works fine.Can you pinpoint the bug in some free time.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having trouble finding the cause. But I do have another fix that is irrelevant to the question: You should remove the `overflow: hidden;" on your `.navbar-toggle` and apply it to your `.onepage-menu` so that your toggle menu looks normal.

Comment: Whwn i rotate my mobile view to landscape problem gets opposite.